# RxJs+Angular Subject called twice

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, reactivex

I'm trying to implement the logic of a selectable list whithout observers, just with a chain of observables, this code works but with a problem:

```
    ngOnInit()
    {
    //Every value emitted tells me if i have to select or unselect the current id.
    let sel_or_unsel = Observable.merge(
      this.idSelected$.map( id => { return {id : id, to_select : true} }),
      this.idUnselected$.map( id => { return {id : id, to_select : false}})
    )
    //Starting from an empty array, add or remove elements
    this.selected_ids$ = sel_or_unsel.scan( (selecteds : [number], id) => {

        if (id.to_select)
        {
          let a = Array.from(selecteds)  
          a.push(id.id)
          return a
        }

        else {
          return selecteds.filter( v => v != id.id)
        }

      }, new Array() )
      .merge(Observable.of(this.initial_selections))

    this.nonselected_ids$ = Observable.combineLatest(this.selected_ids$, this.tab_items$,
      (ids,table) => 
      {
          return _.difference(Array.from(table.keys()),ids)
      })


    this.selected_items$ = Observable.combineLatest(this.selected_ids$, this.tab_items$,
       (ids,table) => ids.map( (id) : [number,T] => [id, table.get(id)])  
    )

    this.nonselected_items$ = Observable.combineLatest(this.nonselected_ids$, this.tab_items$,
      (ids,table) => ids.map( (id) : [number,T]  => [id,table.get(id)])
    )

  }
```

idSelected$ and idUnselected$ are PublishSubjects (Subjects in rxJS), whenever a click occurs on a selected or unselected item I have an angular binding which calls:

```
selectItem(el : [number,T])
  { 
    console.log("SelectItem()")
    this.idSelected$.next(el[0])
  }

  unselectItem(el : [number,T])
  {
    console.log("unselectItem()")
    this.idUnselected$.next(el[0])
  }
```

When i call the operator next e.g. this.idSelected$.next(3) on the subjects, the flow starts working as expected:

- this.idSelected$.map(...) emits [3, true ]
- sel_or_unsel emits [3, true]
- The scan operator is called with parameters ( [], [3,true])
- The scan operator emits [3]
- THEN THE PROCESS REPEATS
- this.idSelected$.map(...) emits [3, true ]
- sel_or_unsel emits [3, true]
- The scan operator is called with parameters ( [], [3,true])
- The scan operator emits [3]

In the end the results are the same, but i don't understand why everything gets repeated twice, I tried using the enableProdMode() but nothing changed.

EDIT: The code is just what i published, no subscriptions are made to the observables.

Comment: There's no `PublishSubject`. Are you sure you're not using `ReplaySubject`?

Comment: I'm Using the rxJS Subject, which as far as i know behaves like a PublishSubject

Comment: There's no `PublishSubject` in RxJS